# Find linear transformation between 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I have matrices:
$
  A = n\overbrace{
\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
      \bullet & \cdots & \bullet\\
      \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
      \bullet & \cdots & \bullet\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right\}
  }^{m_1}\\
  B = n\overbrace{
\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
      \bullet & \cdots & \bullet\\
      \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
      \bullet & \cdots & \bullet\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right\}
  }^{m_2}
$

I would like to find an orthogonal matrix T such that $T = m_1\overbrace{
\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
      \bullet & \cdots & \bullet\\
      \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
      \bullet & \cdots & \bullet\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right\}
  }^{m_2}$
\begin{align}
    T &= \begin{bmatrix}
           t_{1} \\
           t_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           t_{m_1}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}\

for each $t_i, t_j$ such that $i \neq j: \\ t_i \cdot t_j = 0$

And minimizes the function $f(T) = |A T - B|_F$

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If $m_1\ne m_2$, what does it mean to say that $T$ is orthogonal?

Comment: T is orthogonal means that the vectors of T are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: And what are the vectors of a matrix?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I added explanation for the orthogonal part